# Where do I drag a beatmap to import it?

Tags: osu, osudroid

### Note: I'm using osu!droid; the android version, not the PC version, or [osu!laser](https://github.com/ppy/osu).

*The PC location is `<PC Location>\Songs\...` (or literally drag it into the game window)*

Where do I drag a beatmap to import it?
According to the instructions on the [osu! Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20141208231543/http://osu.ppy.sh/wiki/Osu!droid), which simply states to drag the .osz file into osu!droid's folder, which (I may be wrong) is `root/data/data/ru.nsu.ccfit.zuev.osu/files`.

Am I dragging it into the completely wrong location or what? Every time I open osu!droid, it doesn't seem to detect new beatmaps to import... And the in-game map loader doesn't download anything due to the server's high load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my phone, the location is simply `mnt/sdcard/osu!droid/Songs/`.
When importing, drag the beatmap folders, not the individual osz files. No root folder needed.